# How to optimize preprocess all text documents without using for loop to preprocess a single text document in each iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I want to optimize the below code so that it can process the 3000 text data efficiently and that data then will be fed to TFIDF Vectorizer and linkage() for clustering.

So far, I have read the excel using pandas and saved the dataframe into list variable. Then I iterated on the list by each text element in the list into tokens and then filtering out the stopwords from the element. The filtered element is stored into another variable and that variable is stored in the list. So at the end, I created a list of processed text elements(from list).

I think that optimization can be performed when a list is created and when stopwords are filtered out and also while saving the data into two different variables:  documents_no_stopwords and processed_words.

It would be great if someone can help me on this or suggest me a direction to follow.

```
temp=0
df=pandas.read_excel('File.xlsx')

for text in df['text'].tolist():
    temp=temp+1
    preprocessing(text)
    print temp


def preprocessing(word):

    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(word)

    processed_words = []
    for w in tokens:
        if w in stop_words:
            continue
        else:
    ## a new list is created with only the nouns in them for each text document
            processed_words.append(w)
    ## This step creates a list of text documents with only the nouns in them
    documents_no_stopwords.append(' '.join(processed_words))
    processed_words=[]
```

Comment: is `stop_words` a set? if not, turn it into one. Other than that, everything frankly looks fine under preprocessing to me. `.append` is a constant time operation, and `.join` an O(n). If you wanted, you could create the join output during the `for w in tokens` step instead, but it wont help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make `set` of stop words and use list comprehension to filter the tokens.

```
def preprocessing(txt):
    tokens = word_tokenize(txt)
    # print(tokens)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if i not in stop_words]

    return " ".join(tokens)

string = "Hey this is Sam. How are you?"
print(preprocessing(string))
```

Output:

```
'Hey Sam . How ?'
```

And rather than using a `for` loop, use `df.apply` like below:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(preprocessing)
```

**Why sets are preferred over list**

<s>There are duplicate entries in `stopwords.words()`
If you check `len(stopwords.words())` and `len(set(stopwords.words()))`
the length of set is smaller by few hundreds. That's why `set` is preferred here.</s>

Here's the difference between performance using `list` and `set`

```
x = stopwords.words('english')
y = set(stopwords.words('english'))

%timeit new = [i for i in tokens if i not in x]
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop

%timeit old = [j for j in tokens if j not in y]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 µs per loop
```

And furthermore `list-comprehension` is faster than normal `for-loop`.

Comment: That looks good. Why do we prefer set for stopwords.over list? How would the performance be impacted? Both contain the unique elements in this scenario so why a set is better than list?

Comment: I checked the same, and I found out that for english, the length of list of stopwords and the length of set of stopwords are equal. Both equals to 179. faster List comprehension will be a win for sure though.

Comment: @akshit I was so wrong about the length. I have added performance benchmark using `list` and `set` and I hope it is clear now why `set` is prefered over `list`